# Blender model imported in Unity in some parts have wrong material and some of them are black

Tags: .fbx

I have a problem when I import fbx model in Unity. Some parts from one object that is for example extruded have the wrong texture from that object in Unity. As you can see below, that green is the texture of grass but it should be concrete. They are somehow mixed. Do you know how to fix it in Blender because drag and drop textures in Unity cause everything to take that texture?

[image]

Comment: More info, please. Are you using multiple materials, are you using modifiers etc. Best share the .blend, if you did not create the model in Blender, this is a Unity question

Comment: I did create a model in blender, and as I said when I imported it to Unity I saw those mistakes. That's why this question is on Blender StackExchange. I need to know what are my mistakes while working in Blender so I don't do them again.

Black/missing faces were because of normals flipped in the other direction but I can't figure out why materials are messed up.

I am using multiple materials on one object, but I can't share .blend file.

Comment: You're using fbx to transfer to unity, right?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz yes I do, do you have any advice to do it a different way or how to fix it?

Comment: No, FBX is standard, but the problems you are describing sound like the ones you get with .obj, which Unity at some point said are too obsolete to fix, just don't use it. So I was making sure. Without the .blend it's near impossible to tell. Can you delete parts of the model and post half of it?

Comment: One trick that comes to mind: Check the materials both in the .fbx and in the GameObject once you dragged it into the scene. Make sure the no of material slots are the same as in the .blend